Can valence bond theory explain bonding in diiron nonacarbonyl?
After reading Is there an iron–iron bond in diiron nonacarbonyl?, I have tried to interpret the bond formation in diiron nonacarbonyl using valence bond theory (VBT). However, difficulty strikes. The three-center-two-electron bond is interpreted in the following manner:

There is, however, a single electron (in red color). I could not think of any possible overlap with this electron. Does this imply VBT could not describe bonding in this particular coordination complex?

What are the ligands L and X ?

@Maurice I suspect L and X refer to two- and one-electron donors in Green's LXZ notation, respectively.

Second @andselisk - well worth learning, I was lucky enough to be taught it by Malcolm Green himself in the late eighties, was really useful in my finals.

The simple answer to the question is that as MO theory and VBT are exactly equivalent in the limit then yes, VBT can explain this. That doesn't mean the explanation is simple ...

Our teacher told us that its a 'flashing' bond of sorts, ie, only one carbonyl is interacted at a time and they keep interchanging among each other.

Can you label the ligand orbitals in your diagram? From the description it sounds like the two single-electron ligand orbitals shown are both from the L-type ligand? But you're then missing both of the X-type ligand orbitals (each donating one electron to each metal). The X-type ligands can pair their donated single electrons with the two unpaired electrons in each metal giving a formal bond order of 1 for both bonds. Then the L-type ligand's two electrons interact with the empty orbital on both metals, making two 0.5 bonds in the 3c-2e formalism.

I may be wrong, but the diagram in question appears to depict a "five-center-four-electron" bond, rather than a

three-center-two-electron bond

Also, the other two bridging carbonyls are missing from the diagram, so it doesn't make any sense to find the red electrons to be

single

The two bridging X carbonyls should form four two-center-two-electron bonds. All the electrons are paired.

I don't see how the diagram depicts "five-center-four-electron" bond. There are three orbitals from three atoms involved in the formation of three-centered-two-electron bond. https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-three-centre-two-electron-bond. There is only one CO bridge which donates 1 electron to each of the iron atom. Two remaining CO bridges act as 3c-2e which is incompletely described by VB theory. I currently stuck at how the other CO bridge form another 3c-2e bond while there is not enough orbital?

"There is only one CO bridge which donates 1 electron to each of the iron atom." Isn't there 2 of this type and only 1 of  3c-2e type CO bridges? This is how I understood.

"There are three orbitals from three atoms involved..."  The dotted lines lead to 4 orbitals from irons and the ligand itself.

It might help to consider simpler systems first. Let's start with a carboxylate.
Looking only at the $\pi$ system, we have one O atom with one electron in the $p_z$ orbital, one C atom with one electron in the $p_z$ and one anionic O with two electrons in $p_z$.
The simplest formal description is to combine the two unpaired electrons into a single $\pi$ bond of order 1 and leave the lone pair on the anionic O unbonded. But a better representation of the actual electron distribution is to distribute the electrons evenly and create two $\pi$ bonds of order 0.5 and have each oxygen take a -0.5 charge. This is still not quantitatively accurate, but does capture that the oxygens are equivalent. However, it's hard to represent with a simple diagram of valence bond orbitals.
A slightly more complicated case is something like $\ce{SF6}$. For simplicity, let's start with $\ce{S^6+}$ and six $\ce{F-}$ ligands. Assuming that the sulfur $d$ orbitals do not participate in bonding, the $\ce{S^6+}$ has empty $3s$ and $3p$ orbitals available, so four of the flouride ligands can use two electrons each to form S-F bonds with order 1. That leaves two of the flourides as unbonded anions (like the $\ce{O^-}$ in the carboxylate). Again, the better representation is to distribute the electrons evenly and create six S-F bonds of order 2/3.
Now let's consider one of the Fe atoms in $\ce{Fe2(CO)9}$. As you've shown, it starts with eight electrons and nine orbitals. As you've done, we'll make three electron pairs and leave two electrons unpaired, so four Fe orbitals are empty.
Again following from your diagram, we use two electrons from each of the three terminal CO ligands to combine with three empty Fe orbitals to make three Fe-CO bonds of order 1.
Of the three bridging CO ligands, two are "X-type", meaning that they formally donate one electron to each metal, so we take those single electrons and combine them with the two unpaired electrons on Fe to make two more Fe-CO bonds of order 1.
Lastly, we take two electrons from the "L-type" ligand and combine with the final empty Fe orbital to get a sixth Fe-CO bond of order 1.
This last bond is the one that is similar to the C-O $\pi$ bond in the carboxylate. If we do the same process with the second Fe atom, we find that all of the steps are the same, except that the L-type bridging ligand has already given its two electrons to the first Fe-CO bond and formally cannot bond to the second Fe. But as with the other cases, the better representation is to average the full bond and the completely missing bond and get an Fe-CO half-bond to each metal.
Furthermore, we expect that all three bridging CO ligands are equivalent, so we should average the L-type and M-type bonding into six equivalent Fe-CO bridge bonds of order 5/6.
